# Convert HTML to RTF in java?

Tags: java, html, converters, rtf

I need to convert HTML to RTF, and I am using this code:

```
private static String convertToRTF(String htmlStr) {
    OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    HTMLEditorKit htmlEditorKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    RTFEditorKit rtfEditorKit = new RTFEditorKit();
    String rtfStr = null;
    htmlStr = htmlStr.replaceAll("<br.*?>", "#NEW_LINE#");
    htmlStr = htmlStr.replaceAll("</p>", "#NEW_LINE#");
    htmlStr = htmlStr.replaceAll("<p.*?>", "");
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlStr.getBytes());
    try {
        Document doc = htmlEditorKit.createDefaultDocument();
        htmlEditorKit.read(is, doc, 0);
        rtfEditorKit.write(os, doc, 0, doc.getLength());
        rtfStr = os.toString();
        rtfStr = rtfStr.replaceAll("#NEW_LINE#", "\\\\par ");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rtfStr;
}
```

The problem is when I try to convert HTML that had bullets or numbers like this:

> 1. one
> 2. two

This is the HTML:

```
<html><head>
    <style>
      <!--
      -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body contenteditable="true">
     <p style="text-align: left;">
         <ol>
             <li><font face="'Segoe UI'">one</font></li>
             <li><font face="'Segoe UI'">two</font></li>
         </ol>
   </p>
```

And this the convert result:

> onetwo

RTF:

```
{\rtf1\ansi
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil Monospaced;\f1\fnil 'Segoe UI';}

\par
\f1 one\f1 two\par \par
}
```

How can I convert the numbers and bullets?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes I did! and i cant find any solution for this in java code!

Comment: 1. Your `\par`s are off. 2. Do you want to keep track of the correct numbers and insert them as text, or do you want to use an RTF List to have automatic numbers? (The latter is called `\listlevel`.)

Comment: Then add handling for `ol` (to reset the counter) and `li` (to insert the number).

Comment: @Jongware can you write a answer?

Comment: Sorry, no. 1. I don't do Java. 2. You can't use `replaceAll` for this. 3. .. which I probably would not use anyway, in lieu of a proper *tokeniser* and HTML operand stack. (Unless your HTML documents are very small, in which case it would be overkill.)

Comment: Did you consider using a proper HTML parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755230/how-to-convert-html-rtf-in-java?

Answer (score 5):

These libraries might be helpful:

- **[Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)** (open-source; see [basic usage](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/embedding.html) and [API docs](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/xmltools/formatters/fop/fop-0.93/javadocs/index.html))
- **[PD4ML](http://pd4ml.com/index.htm)** (free or commercial; see [HTML2RTF](http://pd4ml.com/cookbook/html_to_rtf_conversion.htm) and [examples](http://pd4ml.com/examples.htm))
- **[Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/java/word-component.aspx)** (commercial; see [docs](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/Product+Overview) and [API](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/com.aspose.words+package))

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee This user isn't posting links to articles where content would be meaningful in the answer; this isn't a *link only* answer, per se.

Comment: Can I see working example of conversion from html to rtf using Apache FOP?

Comment: The issue is that the [FAQ of Apache FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#xhtml-to-pdf) states that [html2fo](http://html2fo.sourceforge.net/) should be used before. This makes it really hard to use...