# How can I start a RTF editor from scratch(using Java)

Tags: java, editor, rtf

I know this may sound silly to some of you experienced guys out there but it’s really important for me and my group at school, we need to create a software that allows the user to create a new RTF document from scratch (like an editor where you can center, change font size, style, save, insert picture), it also needs to be able read a docx document with images and format included and save it as a RTF document.

What we have done so far is being able to open the .docx document, extract the text without format and put it into an RTF document out. In other words using docx4j library we have been able to transform a .docx document text to .rtf, no pictures included, no formatting, just plain text surrounded by [ ].

We have made some progress today but we can’t figure out the next steps, considering the delivery date is in 72 hours, I thought it’d be a good idea to ask for help from more experienced people than us.
Please leave your answers or request info about the project, we’ll be glad to learn from you guys 

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, making it hard to answer without writing a complete tutorial. Much better would be for you to tell us exactly what has you stumped, exactly where you're stuck. Often times the best way for you to do this, and also the best way for you to complete your project is to try to "divide and conquer", to break your big problem into its small constituent steps, and then try to solve each small step one at a time. If a step is especially difficult, then try to subdivide it, and try to solve it in isolation from your big program.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a `.docx` to `.rtf` use a library like https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/. It will do all the heavy lifting for you.

---

Anyway, now about your editor itself. If I had to do it as fast as I could, I would use JavaFX to make my interface. There is a control called "Rich Text Editor" (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/editor.htm) which you can just put into your application.

The trick here is that you can actually extract the HTML of the editor using `getHtmlText()`, and then you can the HTML to RTF using... yes, a library. I suspect that jodconverter can do this too, but if not, you can look at this question: [Convert HTML to RTF in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25956775/5259402).

This should give you a better idea of how to do your project. There are Java libraries to handle conversion between HTML and RTF, so you can use an HTML editor (provided by JavaFX). And of course, a `.docx` can be converted to HTML too. Let libraries do all the dirty work :).